# **how to add 0.15 value , when I am inserting a record in a table ?**

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

Hhow to add 0.15 value , when I am inserting a record in a table ?

[image]

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: Please read about presenting a [minimal reproducible example]9https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  Your question is completely lacking in context.  Remember that no one here knows your system or what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Add *where*?

If your task is to create such a table, a CTAS is one simple option, e.g.

```
SQL> create table salesman as
  2    select 5001 salesman_id, 'James Hoog' name, 'New York' city, 0.15 commision
  3    from dual union all
  4    select 5002, 'Nail Knite', 'Paris', 0.13
  5    from dual;

Table created.

SQL> select * from salesman;

SALESMAN_ID NAME       CITY      COMMISION
----------- ---------- -------- ----------
       5001 James Hoog New York        ,15
       5002 Nail Knite Paris           ,13
```

---

If inserting, then

```
SQL> insert into salesman (salesman_id, name, city, commision)
  2    values (5005, 'Pit Alex', 'London', 0.11);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from salesman;

SALESMAN_ID NAME       CITY      COMMISION
----------- ---------- -------- ----------
       5001 James Hoog New York        ,15
       5002 Nail Knite Paris           ,13
       5005 Pit Alex   London          ,11

SQL>
```

---

If you - as you said want to "add" 0.15 to already existing rows, then it is `update` (not `insert`):

```
SQL> update salesman set commision = commision + 0.15;

3 rows updated.

SQL> select * from salesman;

SALESMAN_ID NAME       CITY      COMMISION
----------- ---------- -------- ----------
       5001 James Hoog New York         ,3
       5002 Nail Knite Paris           ,28
       5005 Pit Alex   London          ,26

SQL>
```

---

If nothing of above, what are you asking, then?